# Setting up IBM Domino Development Server

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus

We are planning to setup new Development and Test environment for Lotus Notes Domino 8.5. We would like users to use same Notes ID that they use to access applications on production server. Any help will be great!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to isolate the development server from production.

Just cross certify your production ID on the development server.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.help.domino.admin.doc/DOC/H_ADDING_CROSS_CERTIFICATES_TO_THE_DOMINO_DIRECTORY_OVER.html

Comment: Thanks, I have isolated development server from production.